# Spring Boot - @Convert doesn't call convertToDatabaseColumn method

Tags: java, spring, encryption

I want to use @Convert to encrypt my DB data and following are my code parts. 
The problem I'm having is when I set @Converter(autoApply = true) it works fine and all the string attributes are perfectly encrypted. 
But when I set it False, the attribute I want to encrypt is not encrypting and convertToDatabaseColumn never gets called. 
What did I missed?

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_offer_log")
public class DbLogTable {

   @Column(name = "id", length=100)
   private int id;

   //Column I want to encrypt 
   @Column(name="msisdn",length=9)
   @Convert(converter = EncryptDecrypt.class)
   private String msisdn;
}
```

Attribute Converter

```
@Converter
public class EncryptDecrypt implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String strToEncrypt) {
        try
        {
            String secret="secret";
            setKey("secret");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you initiated SecretKeySpec with a value, I don't see it in your code

Comment: Yes I did and I have not included those code parts here. The thing is encryption method works fine as when I set autoApply = true it encrypts the value perfectly. But when it is false, this overridden encryption method never been called.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try @Converts at the entity class level like this and see if it works for you?

```
@Entity 
@Converts({
            @Convert(attributeName="msisdn", 
                     converter=EncryptDecrypt.class)})
@Table(name="tbl_offer_log")
public class DbLogTable {

   @Column(name = "id", length=100)
   private int id;

   //Column I want to encrypt 
   @Column(name="msisdn",length=9)
   private String msisdn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. 
Used the @Convert in the getter and setter methods and it works fine now.

```
@Convert(converter = EncryptDecrypt.class)
public String getMsisdn() {
    return msisdn;
}
@Convert(converter = EncryptDecrypt.class)
public void setMsisdn(String msisdn) {
    this.msisdn = msisdn;
}
```